# Emacs Magit: how can I see differences between a given branch and unstaged changes?

Tags: emacs, magit

With git I can see the differences in a file relative to any other past commit as:

```
git diff commit file_name
```

This shows me the differences in `file_name` between the version in `commit` against my current unstaged changes.

With Magit I can choose a given commit with `.` in the log and compare it with another commit with `=`. However I do not see my unstaged changes in the log so how can I select them to make the comparison?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When in the main magit view (which you get after calling `magit-status`), you can press <kbd>d</kbd> to get a menu of all `diff` commands. Then press <kbd>r</kbd> (**r**ange) to diff against a specific commit (which is prompted in the minibuffer).

If you want the exact equivalent to your git command line and limit the diff to a specific file, then press <kbd>=f</kbd> before <kbd>r</kbd> (as always with magit, the "popup" is self-explanatory).

The complete sequence to get an equivalent of `git diff commit file_name` is thus :

- <kbd>d</kbd>
- <kbd>=f</kbd>`file_name`<kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>r</kbd>`commit`<kbd>RET</kbd>